# Criteria to distinguish finite from nonfinite complement clauses?

Tags: clauses, infinitive

What are the differences between finite and nonfinite complement clause? Typologically speaking, what are the criteria I could use to distinguish one from the other two?

While I am not really asking for an analysis of a particular example (rather for criteria in general), here's an example to fuel discussion:

1sg-know Joao-GEN mandioca-ACC eat-NMZ-3POSS 
'I know (that) Joao eats mandioca' 
(lit. 'I know of Joao's mandioca eating.')

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms full-finite and partially-finite. Which model of syntax/grammar are you using?

Comment: OK, let's just stick with finite and nonfinite.

Comment: For starts, **long** before we start assigning names to verbal forms, what language is the example in?

Comment: Undescribed agglutinative Amazonian isolate.

Comment: Outside the bare basics ("finite" and "nonfinite" apply to specific verb forms), we really do need more information to decide how it would work in this language. Is this an assignment or something?

Comment: Finite clauses have subjects; non-finite clauses do not.  (I owe this way of distinguishing the two to Stan Starosta.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though of course more language-specific information is needed, general criteria do exist. The finiteness of a clause is basically how non-nominalised it is (Givón, 2001), and, as is well known, the 'nouniness' of a constituent is gradient rather than absolute (Ross, 1973). Thus, the finiteness of the clause can be described as how few NP-like features it has.

Givón (2001) lists the following criteria. Clauses which satisfy a lot of these are less finite (closer to the prototypical NP), whereas clauses satisfying most of these are the most finite:

> a. The verb becomes a head noun
>   b. The verb takes nominalising morphology
>   c. Tense-aspect-mood distinctions are lost
>   d. Pronominal agreement is lost
>   e. Either the subject or the object acquires nominative case
>   f. Determiners are added
>   g. Adverbs become adjectives

Sources:

Givón, T. (2001). *Syntax: an introduction* (Vol. 2). John Benjamins Publishing.

Ross, John R. (1973), 'Nouniness', in O. Fujimura (ed.), *Three Dimensions of Linguistic Theory* (Tokyo: TEC Company, Ltd.), 137-258.

Comment: @OP, hope you don't mind my late answer. You've probably figured it out long before :P